# Why does $(p_{04}^{(n)})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ not converge?

Tags: markov-chains

Consider a Markov chain with the states 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 and transition matrix
$$
P=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{5} & \frac{3}{5}& 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 &1 & 0 &0&0&0\\0&\frac{1}{3}&0&\frac{2} {3}&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0&5&0\\0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&1&0&0\end{pmatrix}
$$

> Show that 
>   $$
> (p_{04}^{(n)})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}
> $$
>   does not converge as $ n\to\infty$.
>   Determine limsup and liminf of the sequence.

I am wondering why the sequence does not converge because as far as I see it is
$$
p_{04}^{(n)}=\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^n.
$$

which goes to 0 as $ n\to\infty$.

Comment: This is not $p_{04}^{(n)}$. For example one can go from $0$ to $4$ in four steps in two ways, either as $0\to0\to0\to0\to4$ or as $0\to4\to5\to6\to4$, hence $$p_{04}^{(4)}=\left(\frac15\right)^4+\frac15\ne\left(\frac15\right)^4.$$

Comment: Are you sure about the exercise? Showing that $(p^{(n)}_{44})$ has no limit is trivial, but I fail to see a simple argument for $(p^{(n)}_{04})$.

Comment: This is exactly the problem: In our first reading it was said that this has to be done by Perron-Frobenius-Theorem and it was said that this theorem will be given later in the lecture. But now this exercise appears on the first work sheet and we did not have the theorem yet of course.

Comment: One *expects* that $p^{(n)}_{04}$ does not converge because the chain sooner or later enters the cycle $4\to5\to6\to4$... but it could happen that the time and place the chain is entering the cycle are "carefully" distributed so that the cyclic behaviour is evened out. To get rid of this (remote) possibility is not obvious, anyway Perron-Frobenius will not suffice. Close the question?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** here the notation is:

$$
p^{(n)} = n\text{th power of }p\\
p^{(n)}_{04} = (n\text{th power of }p)_{04}
$$

Comment: What shall (nth power of p)_{04} be?

Comment: can't you compute or estimate it? **Hint:** draw the graph corresponding to the Markov chain.

Comment: But I did compute it in my post. Do not know what is wrong with it.